# Write data larger than memory to HDF5 file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, hdf5

I want to save a large dataset matrix 120964x50176 (H5T_IEEE_F32LE) from Matlab as an HDF5 file. I cannot load the the dataset in the memory at once. I have it split into multiple files with sizes like 108x50176, 141x50176, 148x50176. I want to save it in the same dataset in an HDF5 file of size 120964x50176.

There doesn't seem to be much documentation regarding this. I was writing some code but since the chunks are unequal this doesn't seem to be the right direction. How do I write to this dataset in bunches of rows?

```
dims = [120964 50176];
chunk_size = min([100 50176], dims);

fileID = H5F.create('test_features.h5');
dsetname = 'features';
datatypeID = H5T.copy('H5T_IEEE_F32LE');
dataspaceID = H5S.create_simple(2,fliplr(dims),fliplr(dims));
plistID = H5P.create('H5P_DATASET_CREATE');

H5P.set_chunk(plistID, fliplr(chunk_size));
datasetID = H5D.create(fileID, dsetname, datatypeID, dataspaceID, plistID);

rows_seen = 0;
for i=1:size(testset,1)
    filename = strcat('/datasets/',sprintf('%.6d',imdb.testset(i)),'.mat');
    load(filename);
    H5D.write(datasetID,'H5ML_DEFAULT','H5S_ALL','H5S_ALL','H5P_DEFAULT',feat);
    clear('feat');
    rows_seen = rows_seen + frames(i);
end
H5D.close(datasetID);
H5F.close(fileID);
```

Comment: Did you try using `matfile` command to create the file? A mat-file v7.3 is a HDF5 file and `matfile` command supports loading / saving parts of matrices.

Comment: No, I haven't tried that out yet. I'll try to use that. Does it create a regular hdf5 file which I can open using h5py.File() in python?

Comment: It creates regular gzip compressed hdf5 files. Never tested "ugly" things like putting objects into it, but matrices can be loaded in python without problems.

Comment: @Daniel Everything is working now. If you can write this as an answer, I'll accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matfiles `v7.3` are gzip compressed HDF5 files. You can load them with h5py and any other library which has gzip support compiled in.

The nice part about `matfile` is the simple usage:

```
%open
m = matfile(filename,'Writable',1)
%insert some data
m.yourbigmatrix(1:200,1:300)=one_data_block
%get data
one_data_block=m.yourbigmatrix(1:123,1:300)
```